# Where can I find a C# ASP.NET tutorial on how to make a simple content management system?

Tags: c#, asp.net

More specifically, is there any tutorials on how to setup a login system, storing accounts, etc?  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about [www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-forms) ?

- [login & accounts in this video](http://www.asp.net/security/videos/using-basic-forms-authentication-in-aspnet)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try DotNetNuke?

[this is a good website for starters](http://www.dnnhero.com/)

I prefer you dive into an already set-up CMS before thinking of developing your own from scratch, you'll find a lot of smart ideas which will rich users experience in your CMS.

Answer (score 2):

Learn it from the open source project: http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/

Answer (score 2):

this is good one.

[Pro ASP.NET 4 CMS: Advanced Techniques for C# Developers Using the .NET 4 Framework](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781430227120)